# Windows 8, UEFI, "Supervisor" (BIOS) password, linux?

Tags: windows, boot, bios, passwords, uefi

I've got myself a new lenovo c540 PC and there are Windows 8 OS with UEFI option on and "Supervisor" password on, so it's like a loop, I can't load/install ubuntu from my USB (because BIOS is secured). 
Any ideas how to work around apart taking off CMOS and resetting BIOS password?

Cheers!

Comment: If you don't know the password you will need to reset it.  You sure you purchased this laptop new and not used?  Lenovo is required by Microsoft to provide a mechanic to disable `Secre Boot`

Comment: Who set the BIOS password?  As for SecureBoot, [modern versions of Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#SecureBoot) should support it

Answer (score 0):

Most computers provide a way to reset the firmware to factory defaults, which should include no firmware password (although Secure Boot will probably still be active). Check your manual or call Lenovo to find out how to do this.

As to Secure Boot, as already stated, it should be disable-able once the password issue is dealt with. Furthermore, several distributions work with it enabled. Ubuntu should, but that seems problematic based on online reports I've seen. Fedora seems better on that score. OpenSUSE also works with Secure Boot, but I haven't been following it as closely, so I'm not sure how well it works. In theory, you can get *any* distribution to boot with Secure Boot enabled, as described on [my Web page on the topic.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html) The trouble is that you'll need to either modify the installation medium to boot via shim or PreLoader, or temporarily disable Secure Boot to do the installation and then install shim or PreLoader. Installing shim or PreLoader manually can be a bit of a hassle. Thus, for ease of use, it's best to either stick with a distribution that supports Secure Boot or disable the feature entirely.